# How can I create a Dictionary that has its Values expanding depending of how many duplicates is found on the main Dataset?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

The dataset I am using ca be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps
This dataset has two columns that classify the type of App (column 1 and 9 - I am counting starting from the first column being 0). Maybe the image below will help:
[image]

The data from column 1 is less granular than column 9, so the dictionary key would be Column1 while the values Column9. I already got a function to look what is the percentage of each of the Categories in Column 1 to Column 9.

```
def freq_table(dataset, index_category):
table = {}
total = 0

for row in dataset:
    total += 1
    category = row[index_category]
    if category in table:
        table[category] += 1
    else:
        table[category] = 1

table_percentages = {}
cat_num=0
for key in table:
    cat_num+=1
    percentage = (table[key] / total) * 100
    table_percentages[key] = percentage 
print(f'Total Number of Categories: {cat_num}')
return table_percentages

#Removing from being a dictionary and putting in a Descending Order
def display_table(dataset, index_category):
    table = freq_table(dataset, index_category)
    table_display = []
    for key in table:
        key_val_as_tuple = (table[key], key) 
        #The order of this sentence is - Percentage and Category, because the function sorted gets the first element to sort it
        #And this is the Percentage since we want a Descending Order
        #This is a Tuple since we will not need to change these values and it is easy to pack values together
        table_display.append(key_val_as_tuple)
        #In order to pack everything in one object, we use List Append (Tuples don't have Append)
    table_sorted = sorted(table_display, reverse = True) #We choose the Descending Order in the Percentage Field here
    for entry in table_sorted:
        print(entry[1], ':', entry[0], '%') 
        #Before the order was Percentage : Category, now to be more user friendly we change to Category : Percentage
```

But how I can create a function that will tell me the following?

> Family (column0) has the Genres (column9): 'Casual;Brain Games' representing 35%, 'Educational;Creativity' representing 20%, 'Education;Education' representing 45%

Let me know if any further information is needed and **thank you so much for the help.**                            '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use `pandas` for the given file. pandas will read the file in tabular format, and a lot of grouping options will be available -

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv("googleplaystore.csv")
x = x.groupby(["Category", "Genres"], as_index=False)[['App']].count().rename(columns={'App' : 'cnt'})
x_tot = x.groupby(["Category"], as_index=False)[['cnt']].sum().rename(columns={'cnt' : 'tot'})
x = x.merge(x_tot, on = ['Category'])
x['pct'] = x['cnt']/x['tot']
```